# Mercurial CLI is slow in C#?

Tags: c#, mercurial

I'm writing a utility in C# that will make managing multiple Mercurial repositories easier for the way my team is using it. However, it seems that there is always about a 300 to 400 millisecond delay before I get anything back from hg.exe. I'm using the code below to run hg.exe and hgtk.exe (TortoiseHg's GUI). The code currently includes a Stopwatch and some variables for timing purposes. The delay is roughly the same on multiple runs within the same session. I have also tried specifying the exact path of hg.exe, and got the same result.

```
static string RunCommand(string executable, string path, string arguments)
{
    var psi = new ProcessStartInfo()
    {
        FileName = executable,
        Arguments = arguments,
        WorkingDirectory = path,

        UseShellExecute = false,
        RedirectStandardError = true,
        RedirectStandardInput = true,
        RedirectStandardOutput = true,

        WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Maximized,
        CreateNoWindow = true
    };

    var sbOut = new StringBuilder();
    var sbErr = new StringBuilder();

    var sw = new Stopwatch();

    sw.Start();

    var process = Process.Start(psi);

    TimeSpan firstRead = TimeSpan.Zero;

    process.OutputDataReceived += (s, e) =>
    {
        if (firstRead == TimeSpan.Zero)
        {
            firstRead = sw.Elapsed;
        }

        sbOut.Append(e.Data);
    };
    process.ErrorDataReceived += (s, e) => sbErr.Append(e.Data);

    process.BeginOutputReadLine();
    process.BeginErrorReadLine();

    var eventsStarted = sw.Elapsed;

    process.WaitForExit();

    var processExited = sw.Elapsed;

    sw.Reset();

    if (process.ExitCode != 0 || sbErr.Length > 0)
    {
        Error.Mercurial(process.ExitCode, sbOut.ToString(), sbErr.ToString());
    }

    return sbOut.ToString();
}
```

Any ideas on how I can speed things up? As it is, I'm going to have to do a lot of caching in addition to threading to keep the UI snappy.

Comment: You say there is a delay before you get anything back, is this delay the same as the amount of time the program needs to complete? Or does an arbitrary command take 3-400 ms longer to run through your program than it does from the command line? I can't say I've experienced that hg runs slower, but there seems to be some caching on the output. In other words, it seems that my program won't get new lines of text from hg as hg spits them out, only when the buffer fills at some point later.

Comment: Also, I can't resist the urge to do some self-commercial :) I've made a not-yet-finished class library for wrapping Mercurial. You could check out my code to see if there's any obvious differences in the area of executing the program. I'll do some timing tests now, but my unit-tests doesn't take that long to run so I don't think I have such a delay. It's found here: http://mercurialnet.codeplex.com/

Comment: I don't know how long it takes to run from the command line, I'm just finding that 300+ ms is unacceptable when you have 26 (and growing) repositories to run multiple commands on. Just to figure out what branch each one is on takes almost 9 seconds, and I also need to check to see if there's heads that need merging, among other things.

Comment: That sounds odd, please try executing one of those commands from the command line instead and see if it takes 9 seconds then. Ah, ok, now I get it, with 300ms x 26, it will take close to 9 seconds. Well, there's a bit of overhead in running the program, there's no two ways about that.

Comment: Executing a simple `hg heads` command with my library takes 200ms for the Mercurial repository clone I have locally. Identifying the branch takes 180ms, or thereabouts. I looked at your code, and compared to mine, and I can't see any big differences. Here's my file that does the same: http://mercurialnet.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/ddd27e6dfe33#Mercurial.Net%2fClient.cs, the relevant code is in the Execute method a bit down.

Comment: Note that a simple `hg version --quiet` takes 180-200ms on my machine to run, there simply is a bit of overhead in running that program. How about attacking this from a different perspective... why do you have 26 repositories and why do you need to know which branch they're **all** on?

Comment: Well, the idea was to make it easy to get an overview of the state of all of your working copies in one go. See what branches they're on, see which ones have uncommitted changes, etc. It gets pretty hairy when a project references 10 different projects' repositories and you don't remember which ones you made changes to, so you have to check the status of each one... Am I doing it all wrong? :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, here's the deal.

The mercurial command line program contains overhead, that's about it.

This command:

```
hg --quiet version
```

Which doesn't look at any repository at all, takes 195ms on average on my machine to execute. You're not going to be able to minimize this a lot closer to zero when you start involving repositories and changesets.

Why do you have 26 repositories? Why do you need to know which branch they're on? Are you using named branches and multiple repositores at the same time?

Comment: Yes, I'm using multiple repos and named branches. The code is broken into several libraries which get used in different combinations across different projects, so I've been keeping them in separate repositories. I don't want a branch specific to one project cluttering up the branch list for other projects...